# Casting to URLError, then accessing 'code' property causes a crash

Tags: ios, swift

When I case an `Error` as `URLError`, then try to access its 'code' property the app is crashing. I get

> EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).

```
func somFunc(things: [Thing]?,
             error: Error?) {

              let errorCopy = (error as? URLError)
              let errorCode = errorCopy?.code //Crash
}
```

I can understand the casting returning `nil`, or the call on code returning `nil`. But I am not sure of the cause of the crash.

When I print errorCopy before I try to read 'code', I get:

> errorCopy: Optional(Foundation.URLError(_nsError: Error
>   Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=404 "(null)"))

Comment: `let errorCode = errorCopy?.code` it is probably not the source of your crash considering the fact that you are not forcing to unwrap it.

Comment: it is crashing on that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still cannot explain the crash, but I found a work around. Cast the error to an NSError, then read the code property.

```
 let errorCopy = (error as? NSError)
 let errorCode = errorCopy?.code
```

Then I can use the error code without crashing:

```
if errorCode == URLError.cancelled.rawValue {
//Do Something
}
```

Comment: can you explain why it is wrong? it _seems_ to be working. this is just an apparent workaround. I am still searching for the most correct solution.

Comment: can you show the line after the `let errorCode = errorCopy?.code` ? Again it shouldn't crash your app.

Comment: Considering the fact that you said that casting to URLError it is not failing you should switch the error code. check the post below

Comment: that line does indeed crash. its not a force unwrap error, its an EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Comment: The problem is that your error code 404 it is not a valid URLError code